WhatsApp Flows to show a webpage within flows
Webpage inside Flows
I found a service that is loading a full webpage inside WhatsApp flows. Has anyone done it before and knows how to implement it?
I searched the complete META documentation, but had no luck. I did not find any code on META documentation, checked ChatGPT it does not know either

As per the answer here https://github.com/WhatsApp/WhatsApp-Flows-Tools/issues/14

Displaying a website in Flows is currently being tested with specific partners only. Unfortunately, there is no way to request access to this feature at the moment.
Keep an eye on Flows changelog page to learn about new features as they are released https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/changelogs

